# Is there a full explanation (with pseudocode) of corner detection with the Moravec Operator?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, corner-detection

I can't seem to find a thoroughly explained pseudocode/algorithm for corner detection using Moravec's operator.

If anyone can provide one here, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Harris's original paper on corner detection summarizes Moravec's detector in a few lines and discusses the cons. Concise and useful.

Answer (score 0):

For a `k x l` window, calculate the squared gradient sums of the 4 main directions:

[image]

where `p = 2*k + 1` and `q = 2 * l + 1`

If `V` is above a certain threshold, you found a point of interest.

Here's Moravecs's publication: http://www.frc.ri.cmu.edu/~hpm/project.archive/robot.papers/1977/aip.txt

Comment: Why do the (i,j) in the summation start from -k?
I mean our image array is positively indexed.

Comment: @hsnsd that's the definiton I found. I presume the window width is actually p x q, not k x l..   having the central pixel of a window at 0,0 is quite common in image processing. it's the offset to the image coordinate you place the window over.